# Organizing images extracted from a PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a piece of code that gathers images from a PDF and saves them in a folder using pdfBox.  The images are useless because I dont know anything about them.  The PDF contains section headers followed by 1-3 pictures.  Is there anyway to change the program so that it will tell me which section they are coming from?

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        PDDocument document = null; 
        try {
            document = PDDocument.load("C:\\Users\\564864\\Downloads\\wsh2012.pdf");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("" + ex);
        }
        List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        Iterator iter = pages.iterator(); 
        int i =1;
        String name = null;

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) iter.next();
            PDResources resources = page.getResources();
            Map pageImages = resources.getImages();
            if (pageImages != null) { 
                Iterator imageIter = pageImages.keySet().iterator();
                while (imageIter.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) imageIter.next();
                    PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage) pageImages.get(key);
                    image.write2file("C:\\Users\\564864\\Desktop\\Java\\helloworld\\images\\" + i+"");
                    i ++;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the PDF contains additional metadata, there are no sections inside a PDF. I wrote an article on structured text (which equally applies to images) at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2012/06/extracting-structured-text-from-pdf-files/